# Sublime text 2 keyboard layout changed randomly on Ubuntu

Tags: sublimetext2

Sublime text keyboard layout appears to have changed randomly during coding. Not sure how it happened. Keyboard is UK layout. What used to be " (Shift + 2) now give @ instead! Anyone can help? The swap between @ and " is just one, there are lot more messed up keys.

Comment: Did you change to a US layout or another non-UK layout somehow, maybe? Shift-2 on US keyboard is @.

Comment: @DanLowe, nope, haven't changed the keyboard layout in any way. I googled for this and have come across people accidentally hitting some shortcut that changes the layout. Haven't come across anything that fixes this on Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

Never mind guys, hit the shortcut on the top left corner of the desktop that changed the layout to US from UK. It looks like so 'En' with a subscript of 1 or 2.

Comment: This shortcut is left Alt + Shift :)